# How to target tag a inside div with this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, loops

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <div class="block" id="${item.id}" data-num="${item.itemRead}">
        <a id="${item.id}"
            href="javascript:showFeedItem('${item.id}','${item.itemRead}');">
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Why do I have undefinded attribute name data-num when creating a new data attribute `data-num`?
jQuery:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.block').each(function(i, obj) {
                if($(this).attr("data-num")=="0"){
                   //need to style a inside this
                    $(this).css("background-color","black");
                }
            });
        });
```

How to target `a` like this:

```
 $('.block[id="' + id + '"] a').css('color', 'black');
```

but using `$(this).css("background-color","black");`?

Comment: `$('a', this).css("background-color","black");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `this` as the context to jQuery selector

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.block').each(function (i, obj) {
        if ($(this).attr("data-num") == "0") {
            //need to style a inside this
            $('a', this).css("background-color", "black");
            //or $(this).find('a').css("background-color", "black");
        }
    });
});
```

You can also shorten this to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.block[data-num="0"] a').css("background-color", "black");
});
```

Comment: Why do I have undefinded attribute name data-num when creating a new data attribute data-num?

Comment: @RuslanLomov sorry what do you mean

Comment: Thx for your answer. I have attention in my IDE when creating new data data-num="${item.itemRead}"

Answer (score 0):

If you want grab direct descendant of `this` (like it is in your code), you can use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

`$(this).children(a).css("background-color","black");`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change this:

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <div class="block" id="${item.id}" data-num="${item.itemRead}">
        <a href="javascript:showFeedItem('${item.id}','${item.itemRead}');">
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

removed `id="${item.id}"` from the anchor. What seemed to me that you are adding same ids to different items in a single page but it has to be unique for each element.

Now in the js you have to use `.find()` to style the anchor and style it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.block').each(function(i, obj) {
        if($(this).attr("data-num")=="0"){ // or if($(this).data("num")=="0"){
            $(this).find('a').css("background","black");
        }
    });
});
```